# erlang: Distributed Hash Table?

Tags: erlang, hashtable, distributed-caching, riak

Are there any Distributed Hash Table implementations in Erlang? I searched the web and found a number of research papers but I did not find a mature implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Riak](http://wiki.basho.com/) is quite mature and mostly implemented in Erlang. It's a bit more than just a DHT.

Comment: Thanks - that's interesting. I'm trying to determine if there's a way in Riak to use in-memory (only) tables; if so it looks good for what I need.

Comment: You can customize the back end storage, there is a storage_backend setting for it. ETS, which is in-memory, is one of the options.

Answer (score 2):

Redis is an incredibly fast implementation I have used with success before, and there is a great Erlang binding for it : http://streamhacker.com/2009/12/21/erldis-erlang-redis-client/